# xamarin intellisense not working in visual studio 2015 on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have been trying to use Xamarin with Visual Studion 2015 on Windows 10 platform. I am not able to use Intellisense for AXML, which is quite frustrating . Any solutions ???

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the xsd-schemas for android layout files to Visual Studio.

Copy `android-layout-xml.xsd` and `schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\schemas` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas`

You can then "Add" these schemas inside Visual Studio via the `XML -> Schemas -> Add` dialog.

It's described in the [Xamarin Knowledgebase](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files-).

Comment: I am not having the Xamarin Studio folder in my Program Files. Did I miss something in installation? I am having just one folder named Xamarin->Bonjour.

Comment: Is the "Xamarin Studio"-folder completely missing? It's not inside the "Xamarin"-Folder but directly under "Program Files".

Comment: Yes sir, its missing.  I looked thoroughly.

Comment: I have access to 2 computers with an Installation of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 with Xamarin. Both computers have such a folder. That's strange. Did you chose a different installation path in the installer? Maybe you can search for the filenames on your computer?

Comment: No, it was a custom installer. I will try to re-install it if u suggest!

Comment: Just wanted to ask, this folder gets created via Xamarin installation or Xamarin Android Player installation? I downloaded Xamarin for VS since, I already had VS2015 installed.

Comment: I just checked a computer in the company which has a Xamarin but no Xamarin Android Player installation. The folder is present anway. It's very strange that the folder is not present on your system.

Comment: Sir, Can you provide me  the link from where you downloaded and installed ? I am really stuck at the moment.

Comment: I tried Unistalling Xamarin and then re-installing Xamarin from https://www.xamarin.com/download

Answer (score 0):

Here what worked actually.....thanks to BOB! (not really)

Do both add the two schema files to your project and open with XML Text editor and not the default Android Designer......

and go to hell bob.

from solution [Cannot get Xamarin Xaml Intellisense working in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037900/cannot-get-xamarin-xaml-intellisense-working-in-vs-2015)

The reason why Intellisense is not appear in editor is that Xamarin XAML is not opened as file with content type xaml but file with content type xml.
To open xamarin XAML file as file with content type xaml simply in solution explorer right click the xaml file and select Open With... In popup select "XAML Designer with Encoding" and click OK.

You need to add the xsd-schemas for android layout files to Visual Studio.

Copy android-layout-xml.xsd and schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd from C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\schemas to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas

You can then "Add" these schemas inside Visual Studio via the XML -> Schemas -> Add dialog.