# Why visual studio 2015 not supporting intellisense support for xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

recently after build 2016 of Microsoft, I have install xamarin for visual studio 2015.
The key part of vs is its intellisense feature and that is not supported when working with .axml files.

Please suggest

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425345/xamarin-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio supports Intellisense for Android .axml files, but you must enable this first. For enabling this feature, read [How do I enable Intellisense in Android .axml files?](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1920119-how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-android-axml-files-) - If you didn't find the files in the mentioned directory (see article), you could download these from GitHub:

[android-layout-xml.xsd](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd)

[schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I had already tried this.
but below mentioned files 
1) android-layout-xml.xsd

2) schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd 

are not available in my system

Comment: I updated the answer. If you didn't find the files, you can download these from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2015.

Link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60962/enable-intellisense-for-axml-missing-android-layout-xml-xsd-schemas-android-com-apk-res-androiod

- Download "android-layout-xml.xsd" and "schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd" from:
  https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen
- Put all downloaded files into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Xml\Schemas
- Open .axml file and click *XML/Schemas* menu in the Visual Studio. Then add correspondent files to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin for Visual Studio includes **out of the box** xsd-based intellisense support starting with our **cycle 7** builds. (XamarinVS 4.1.0.x).

You can try it right now switching to the Beta channel. In Visual Studio go to:

*`Tools - Options - Xamarin - Other`*

Select the *`Beta`* channel, and press *`Check now`*

Keep in mind that if you're developing for Xamarin.iOS, you will need to switch to the Beta channel your Mac as well. That can be done from Xamarin Studio in the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Visual Studio, but you need a Xamarin Studio installation to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Intellisense in Android .axml files:

- Download or copy android-layout-xml.xsd into Visual Studio folder\Xml\Schemas
- open catalog.xml and add line after last :
  http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'     />
- Save catalog.xml and restart (or start) Visual Studio.

  Intellisense in .axml files should work by default. (Maybe you need add a schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd file too.)

Shem's files:  https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen