# Cannot get Xamarin Xaml Intellisense working in VS 2015

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I've been trying to get intellisense working for quite some time now, and am unable to see anything outside of

```
!
![CDATA[
?
```

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 2
- Resharper is installed but disabled
- Referencing the latest pre-releases of Xamarin Forms (2.3.0.38-pre2)
- Xamarin for Visual Studio (4.2.21)
- Portable project referencing the proper 2.3.0.38-pre2 targets file from NuGet
- Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms

What else am I missing? I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 18):

I resolved this issue by doing a simple workaround and here is the solution.

Right-click the XAML file in the Solution Explorer and select

**Solution 1:** "Open With... > **Source Code (Text) Editor**".

and in another time this also worked for me:

**Solution 2:** "Open With... > **Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding**"

This workaround gave me the desired XAML IntelliSense even without installing the extra "Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms" extension and even with ReSharper installed but suspended.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, no Resharper, latest Xamarin.Forms - this worked without having to install anything. Would not have thought Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding.

Comment: does this problem still persist?

Answer (score 7):

Extensions > Tools > Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms

> Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms
>
> Enables the VS built-in XAML language service to provide editing and intellisense for Xamarin.Forms XAML files.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8195a8e2-a842-4389-a8cb-34e4672e2e13

#### Update:

From @Jeff:

> Seems I had to completely uninstall Resharper, not just disable it. Then reinstall the "Enable XAML Language for Xamarin Forms extension".

#### Additional info:

http://www.cazzulino.com/enable-xaml-forms-intellisense.html

#### Xamarin XAML Enabled:

[image]

#### XML Enabled and thus no Xamarin XAML Intellisense:

[image]

Comment: I apparently have that installed as well, forgot to list it.  This does not help either.

Comment: @Jeff See my updates, are your `<?xml version...`  highlighted red or black?

Comment: At the bottom of that article in the comments others are stating it doesn't work with Update 2.

Comment: @Jeff Working fine for us, maybe it was due to having it already installed working before the upgrade? Also did a bunch of fresh workstation images this past weekend to push out, fresh Win10, plus all the goodies, they are working fine in this regard....

Comment: I reinstalled it but with it enabled and disabled it looks like image 2.  Not sure what the deal is here.   
http://i.imgur.com/iehWruv.png

Comment: Thanks for your help @SushiHangover, posted what I ended up having to do above.

Comment: Looks like the link to the extension is dead as of this comment

Comment: we are on Vs 2019 after 5 years and this problem still exist. shame on you microsoft. instead of making collectionview and other things, concentrate on big things

Answer (score 7):

The reason why Intellisense is not appear in editor is that **Xamarin XAML is not opened as file with content type xaml but file with content type xml**.

To open xamarin XAML file as file with content type xaml simply in solution explorer right click the xaml file and select **Open With...** In popup select **"XAML Designer with Encoding"** and **click OK**. 

Solution below is if you edit Xamarin xaml as file with content type xml. But this solution is not correct, IntelliSense then not always correctly suggests.


<s>To take advantage of Intellisense the Visual Studio must get appropriate definition of xml namespace for Xamarin.Forms. For the **Xamarin.Forms** Visual Studio needs xml definition for namespace **http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms**.

This definition can be provided to Visual Studio by two ways:</s>

1. You can use xsd file and this file then register to xml schemas - after you open xaml file, the menu *Xml/Schemas* appear.
2. You can this definition create by assembly attribute **XmlnsDefinitionAttribute**. This attribute you can found in **Portable.Xaml** nuget package.

Suitable for Xamarin.Forms is the second way(using attribute).

If you use Xaml in portable library, restore(download and install) this nuget package to this library.
If you use shared project, then restore this nuget package to all projects referencing this shared project.

Then insert this attribute to appropriate place. I believe that the App.xaml.cs(if you use generated name App) is a good place. The code could look like this:

```
using Portable.Xaml.Markup;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms", "Xamarin.Forms")]

namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            this.MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

And the rebuild solution, as I believe, might not be necessary to work Intellisense for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: You cannot use the XAML Designer with Xamarin, only WPF XAML.

Comment: I didn't claim anywhere I wanted to use XAML Designer with Xamarin! When I chose the menu "XAML Designer with Encoding", so I then did not use the designer (that I minimized). I used only coding.

Comment: The XAML Designer code editor's intellisense is for WPF, not Xamarin so would no use editing Xamarin Forms XAML due to a large difference in tags and syntax. So my original statement is correct.

Comment: You're right, but not entirely. When create WPF, the XAML begins, for example: 
<UserControl x:Class="..."         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
With Xamarin XAML begins:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamlSamples.MainPage">

So when the XAML interprets namespaces, it can edit it.

Answer (score 5):

**This worked for me:**

**right click on .xaml** file and then select **"*Open With..*"** and **select *"XAML Designer"*** and also ***"Set as Default"*** then intellisense worked great.

[image]

Comment: best solution. no need to install any extension. Only you need to indicate that "right click on a xaml file on the solution explorer, not on windows explorer"

Answer (score 4):

I install the `Extension` **Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms** from

[Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8195a8e2-a842-4389-a8cb-34e4672e2e13)

Still the `intellisense` was not working. I just need to close all tabs and close the visual studio. After `re-starting` Visual studio I open solution and XAML file. The `instellisense` is working fine.

Comment: I've also experienced the same problem recently, I'm unsure if it's the Xamarin or Visual Studio update, anyhow, this solution works perfectly! Intellisense is working again, thanks :)

Comment: As per this answer, restarting alone and reloading the project was not enough. I too had to close the XAML files explicitly and reopen them.

Answer (score 2):

[worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da4xT.png)
Right click on Your XAML file and choose Option
Open With=>Source Code(Text) Editor with Encoding=>Set as default=>Apply and choose option Auto....

Comment: this works for me, all I need to do is; after setting above settings I close all files and restart VS. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had to completely uninstall Resharper, not just disable it.  Then reinstall the Enable XAML Language for Xamarin Forms extension.

Comment: Update: I was not on latest Xamarin release.

Answer (score 0):

[Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37038663/888165) almost worked for me, but I had to do one additional step:

Because I had previously uninstalled and reinstalled Xamarin, I had to update from 4.0.1 to the latest stable (4.1.1.3 as of this date). After that Intellisense started working!

Answer (score 0):

I have Resharper installed on VS2015update3, and **XAML Designer** didn't work for me.

But accidently I found **XML (Text) Editor** works. That's **Resharper** that makes effet.

- No wave-line beneath the tag
- Perfect prompt everywhere: XML Tags, Properties, available Values

Only things: it doesn't color too much, and F7 do not send me to its code-behind.

Voilà, hope this could help

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved this issue by doing a simple workaround and here is the
>   solution.
>
> Right-click the XAML file in the Solution Explorer and select
>
> **Solution 1: "Open With... > Source Code (Text) Editor".**
>
> and in another time this also worked for me:
>
> **Solution 2: "Open With... > Source Code (Text) Editor with Encoding"**

Actually, I found that for me it even worked by simply choose:
**Solution 2: "Open With... > Automatic Editor Selector (XML)" and then reopening VS.**

I also found that the problem began after editing .xaml file outside of VS, by right-clicking the file and choose "Edit".