# Can't get XAML Intellisense to work in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I've been having trouble getting XAML intellisense to work on VS2015. I've tried uninstalling and installing Xamarin and VS 2015 multiple times with no success.

I also tried what was mentioned in this thread [Cannot get Xamarin Xaml Intellisense working in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037900/cannot-get-xamarin-xaml-intellisense-working-in-vs-2015)
But I don't have the resharper installed so that shouldn't be an issue.

I see that I am getting the XML version and not the XAML version of the markup which is strange. An example of that is shown in this blog http://www.cazzulino.com/enable-xaml-forms-intellisense.html

Screenshots in a post to follow since I don't have enough rep points.

Comment: Looks like the mods deleted my screenshots....