# Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio and Intellisense

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I need to find an Extension or something like this to fix my XAML Intellisense when I want to use a Xamarin.Forms project.

I know Resharper and it work good to fix my auto-complete, but I'm going to teach how to use Xamarin to studens, and they can"t use Resharper for 3 days.

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: jetbrains has educational licenses

Comment: I'm a student too, and it's just for 3 days :/

Comment: does it have to be VS in this case ? Xamarin Studio offers "OK" intellisense

Comment: I don't understand, all the students have VS, and we can't download Xamarin Studio for Windows

Comment: Please check this questions has the exact answer:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037900/cannot-get-xamarin-xaml-intellisense-working-in-vs-2015/40870538#40870538)

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this post here: [Cannot get Xamarin Xaml Intellisense working in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676483/1271566) you can install this addon to get Intellisense for XAML working again:

[Enable XAML Language for Xamarin.Forms](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8195a8e2-a842-4389-a8cb-34e4672e2e13)