# Xamarin Forms intellisense working for some attributes only

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and Xamarin 4.2.1.62 (the latest stable). The issue I have is that when editing a Xamarin Forms file (.xaml), I don't get IntelliSense for all elements' attributes. For example, with `StackLayout`, I get suggestion for `Orientation`, but not for `HorizontalOptions` or `BackgroundColor` (although both are definitely valid attributes):

[image: IntelliSense working]
[image: No IntelliSense]

I've tried all the different suggestions from this question: [Cannot get Xamarin Xaml Intellisense working in VS 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037900/cannot-get-xamarin-xaml-intellisense-working-in-vs-2015), but no luck:

- The suggested extension is no longer available.
- I don't use ReSharper.
- When I try to open the XAML file by right clicking -> Open with... and selecting XAML Designer, I get an error saying "*The file cannot be opened with the selected editor. Please choose another editor.*"

Is there some way to get the IntelliSense working for all attributes? Or is this normal currently?

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue recently, which I resolved following these steps:

1. Update to latest stable version of Xamarin from *Tools>>Options>>Xamarin>>Other* and check now, download and install latest update.
2. Right click on solution explorer and click on *Manage NuGet Packages For solution*. select all the projects which are in your solution and update the version of Xamarin.Forms in all projects.
3. Now go to your PCL project and add a single new XAML page, you can check that Intellisense will now work, but only on that page.
4. Now Close the solution and restart the system, re-open your project, and your problem shoudl now be solved.