# VS2017 - How do I get intellisense to work on .AXML file?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

How do I get intellisense to work on my .AXML file. I've already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896428/visual-studio-2017-intellisense-not-working-in-android-cs-file), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425345/xamarin-intellisense-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015-on-windows-10/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037900/cannot-get-xamarin-xaml-intellisense-working-in-vs-2015) and more. But all the answers I got did nothing.

Please note that I did not installed Xamarin studio.

Thanks

Comment: What's you mean "the intellisense seems to not being that "intelligent"", could you please elaborate a bit more about this?

Comment: It was just a joke about the intellisense.